# Unable to access kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, gcloud

I have a Kubernetes cluster deployed on gcloud, and I have a couple of services running on it.

The services have been running for some months now.

Today I received a complaint from a client that he **cannot access the services**. I logged in to gcp, and **I cannot see the services in the cluster**.

Kindly look at the attached image for advice. The screenshot is shared below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the cause of your problem may be cluster auto-upgrade. Please have a look at this [document](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/cluster-upgrades) to find more details and at the third party [example](https://medium.com/retailmenot-engineering/zero-downtime-kubernetes-cluster-upgrades-aab4cac943d2).

Could you please share records from `Logging - > Logs Viewer` to get more information about last events with your cluster?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Serhii Rohoza. I figured that there had been changes in the billing information. Someone had inadvertently, removed the credit card details from the billing information. Replacing the credit card details had restored all services.